# Show that $|\text{Re}(2+3z^2 +iz)| \leq 6$, when $|z|\leq 1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Show that  $|\text{Re}(2+3z^2 +iz)| \leq 6$, when  $|z|\leq  1$.

Not really sure where to go this inequality. I know that you need to start with the triangle inequality and do it two times but I am confused on the way it is supposed to turn out.

Comment: is this $$|\Re(2+3z^2+iz|\le 6$$?

Comment: @stacy Welcome to MSE. Please take a look at the MathJax commands for formatting math here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @stacy Does $3(z)2$ mean $3z^2$?

Comment: yes my apologies it was supposed to be an exponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for any complex number $w$, 
$$|w|^2=|\text{Re}(w)|^2+|\text{Im}(w)|^2\geq |\text{Re}(w)|^2\implies |w|\geq |\text{Re}(w)|.$$ 
From the geometric point of view, it means that the hypotenuse is the longest side of a right-angled triangle.
Hence
$$|\text{Re}(2+3z^2 +iz)|\leq |2+3z^2 +iz|.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! this is what I had on my paper, but was confused on showing the steps in order to get to |2+3z^2+iz|≤ |2| + |3z^2| + |iz|. Then after getting that I need to do the triangle equality a second time correct?

Comment: @stacy I revised my answer. Is it clear now?  From $|2| + |3z^2| + |iz|$ use the property $|zw|=|z|⋅|w|$ and the fact that $|z|\leq 1$.

Comment: Yes it is clear now! What if the second z was expressed as the conjugate of z...is there a different step?

Comment: @stacy Do you mean $|\text{Re}(2+3\overline{z}^2 +iz)| \leq 6$? Same approach!